# How to use this package in laravel : orchestra/parser=~3.0 in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

what is the namespace to be used in controller for orchestra/parser=~3.0 package in laravel. I need to convert the xml data to json and print the decoded json data in my view. So suggest me solution to use this package.

Comment: Isn't that explained in the readme section of the package's github repo https://github.com/orchestral/parser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace registered in composer as `Orchestra\\Parser\` [More Here](https://github.com/orchestral/parser/blob/master/composer.json#L15).

```
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Reader as XmlReader;
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Document as XmlDocument;
...
$parser = new XmlReader(new XmlDocument(app()));
$xml = $parser->load('path/to/file.xml');
```